# sending json object to jsonresult controller asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am sending ajax request to my mvc controller.i am sending an object to mvc controller object it shows null there.

```
       function add()
        {

         var viftech =
           {
              "id": $("#id").val(),
               "name": $("#name").val(),
               "lastname": $("#lastname").val(),
               "address": $("#address").val()
        };
        var datasent = viftech;
        console.log(datasent);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/VIftech/insertemployee",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(datasent),
            success: function(data) {
           data ? alert("It worked!",+response.i) : alert("It didn't work.");
           }
          });
    }
```

my mvc controller is like this.note viftech object class have same paramters like id,name,lastname,and address.
if i specify multiple parameters like that i am getting values.

```
public JsonResult insertemployee(string id,string name,string 
 lastname,string address)
```

if i specify object it always null i have used several methods but it dont works.

```
public JsonResult insertemployee(Viftech viftech)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viftech.name))
        {
            return Json("badreques", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(Viftechdb.add(viftech),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Try some thing like this in your controller and then deserialize.  
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

Comment: So you are getting a `null` object or an empty object ? How does your `Viftech` class definition looks like ?

Comment: Your code should work fine as long as your `Viftech` class properties has the same name as the object keys you are sending from Javascript and those has `set` access modifiers.

Comment: @Shyju @shyju my viftech class properties are same as my input  see my class. i am still getting an null object in my parameter dont know why                      `public class Viftech
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string lastname;
        public string address;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form data is submitted, the default model binder will try to read the form data and assign the values to the corresponding **properties** of the view model object. Model binder will be able to successfully do so if your view model class has **set**table properties which has matching name/structure with the form data coming in.

In the code you shared, you are not creating a property but fields inside the `Viftech` class definition. Hence the model binder cannot set the value for that.

To fix the problem, change all of them to **set**table properies by specifying the `set` and `get` property accessors.

```
public class Viftech 
{ 
     public int id { set;get; }  
     public string name { set;get; }   
     public string lastname { set;get; }   
     public string address { set;get; }   
}
```

**Side node:** I would also suggest using PascalCasing for property names.

`public string Name { set;get; }` 
instead of `public string name { set;get; }`

Comment: nice approach thanks a lot. i was struggling so much i need to understand the difference now between fileds and props. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need name the parameter in your object. The object needs a property viftech to indicate the parameter name, else it will try and bind to id, name and lastname.

```
  var viftech =
               {viftech:{
                  "id": $("#id").val(),
                   "name": $("#name").val(),
                   "lastname": $("#lastname").val(),
                   "address": $("#address").val()
            }};
            var datasent = viftech;
            console.log(datasent);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/VIftech/insertemployee",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(datasent),
                success: function(data) {
               data ? alert("It worked!",+response.i) : alert("It didn't work.");
               }
              });
```